# Installing debian 7 besides windows 8

Tags: linux, windows-8, partitioning, debian, uefi

I bought a VAIO laptop which Windows 8 preinstalled on it in UEFI mode.
Now I want to install Debian 7 besides Windows 8 but when I entered to the **Partition Setup** of debian setup menu, there is a partition which named **EFI partition system**.

My question is do I have to create another partition for debian to boot in UEFI? or **EFI partition system** which belongs Windows8 is enough?

And if I have to create another EFI boot partition for Debian 7, What name should I choose for it? And do I have to delete **EFI partition system**?

Thanks,

Comment: See if this helps you in any way: http://liliputing.com/2012/10/linux-foundation-solves-uefi-secure-boot-problem-youll-be-able-to-install-linux-on-most-windows-8-pcs.html

Answer (score 1):

The [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) holds boot loaders and related files. It's intended to be shared between OSes, so you should be able to use a single ESP for both Windows and Linux. In fact, that's preferable to using multiple ESPs because the Windows installer reacts badly to the presence of multiple ESPs; it tends to get confused and hangs mid-install. (At least, that was true of Windows 7; I haven't tried with Windows 8.) That said, the EFI spec does explicitly permit multiple ESPs, so this is definitely a Windows bug.

Previous versions of Debian and Ubuntu had a bug that caused them to wipe the contents of the ESP during installation. I haven't checked the latest Debian to see if this bug has been fixed, but I recommend caution on this score; you should back up the ESP using Windows or a Linux live CD before installing Debian. If the installer erases the ESP, you'll then be able to restore your Windows boot loader from your backup.